# Working with orientation change in mono for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, orientation-changes

I've used following code snippet for my activity in order to deal with orientation change.

```
[Activity (Label = "Activity",ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation 
| ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```

and

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);
            if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("landscape");
            } 
            else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("portrait");
            }
        }
```

I start with `Portrait` mode, then switch to `Landscape mode` and again switch back to `Portrait` mode. So the expected output should be:

```
landscape

portrait
```

but  **Console Output** shows

```
landscape

landscape

portrait
```

i.e. When switching from `Landscape mode` to `Portrait` mode, **if** and **else** both gets executed.

I've no idea why this is happening.

I'm absolute beginner to *Mono for Android*, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this its working ...

1) declare above `oncreate()`

```
int prev_orientation =0;
```

2) overide  below  method:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if(prev_orientation!=orientation){
            prev_orientation = orientation;
        if(orientation ==1){            
            //por
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ort::pot"+orientation,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(orientation ==2){
            //land
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ort::land"+orientation,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

3) Add below line in manifeast file of activity:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code

```
if (Resources.Configuration.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); //set layout for Landscape mode
}
else
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainPortrait); //set layout for Portrait mode
}
```

Comment: Could you explain for those reading how this is an answer to the question, and what it does that solves the question?

Comment: he wants to deal with Orientation change right? it is the same with the answer of Hasmukh but mine is in monodroid. with this code you can deal with orientation change. the difference is that TS wants to do a Console.WriteLine, but mine will open a specific layout for each orientation.

Answer (score 0):

i am pasting code here..try this..

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration orient) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(orient);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (orient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
                      //code here for LANDSCAPE..
        ));   

        }
        else if (orient.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {           
                      //code here for PORTRAIT ..   
            }               
    }
```

Call Method Like;

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        onConfigurationChanged(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }
```